# Как сделать чтобы прелоадер плавно скрывался?

Tags: css3, html5, css-animation

Нужно сделать, чтобы прелоадер плавно скрывался с левого нижнего угла после загрузки страницы, примерно так:

[image: шаг 1]

[image: шаг 2]

[image: шаг 3]

Рылся в гугле и ничего не нашел, если кто поможет - заранее спасибо

```css
.loaderArea {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #010712;
}

.loaderArea .loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 18%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.loaderArea .loader img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="loaderArea loader-end">
  <div class="loader">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martz90/hex/512/css-3-icon.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
</div>
```